# What useful arguments can I give to a #!/usr/bin/php line?

Tags: php

I'm writing a command line utility in PHP.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    print "Hello, world!"
?>
```

Are there any useful flags I should add to the `#!` line? For example, with Perl I might write `#!/usr/bin/perl -w`

I want checking and warnings to be as tight as possible, so that errors, ambiguities, or non-portable features are caught as aggressively as possible.

Comment: iirc error reporting should already be on cli on `-1 / E_ALL`. If not you can either change it in the `php.ini` or just use `error_reporting(-1);` inside the script.

Comment: Not so much the binary line, but more the PHP opening line should have `<?php declare(strict_types=1);` to prevent type juggling of function/method arguments.

Comment: As an aside: `/usr/bin/perl -w` is not considered a good practice, as it enables warnings in _all_ modules, including modules that may expect them to be off.

Comment: Full list of CLI options: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** I would one of the following:

- `#!/usr/bin/php -q -c /location/to/known/php.ini/file` if I have access to a proper pre-configured `php.ini` for the script
- `#!/usr/bin/php -q -n -d error_reporting=-1` if I don't

**Long version**

[Here are](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) the command line options you can use.

While it's not mandatory, you might add `-q`, as that will suppress outputting the HTTP headers, if for some weird reason PHP thinks you are running in a CGI context.

For the rest, one useful could be the `-c <path>|<file>` options, where you can supply the `php.ini` file location to use, where you can set the error level (and other config values) to what you think it's convenient. You can potentally supply the `php.ini` with your script and make sure it's picked up when php starts, so you can have a common environment, especially if you have to run your script on a machine where you don't have full control over the default `php.ini` settings.

If for some reason you can't supply your full `php.ini` with the script, but still want to override the settings in the (potentially unknown) `php.ini`, the other useful option is `-d foo[=bar]` where you can set configuration values. For example `-d error_reporting=-1` would set error reporting to `E_ALL`. You might want to sue this setting with `-n`, which will simply discard any `php.ini` on your path. Note that `-n` might have some side effects, as it will essentially remove all config, and the defaults might not be as sensible as you think.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo ini_get('error_reporting');
echo $unknown;
```

might return

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.1
Content-type: text/html

0
```

in case the PHP interpreter at your location is the CGI one instead of the CLI one, and the default `php.ini` has `error_reporting` turned off. This is probably not something you want.

On the other hand if you try with

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q -n -d error_reporting=-1
<?php
echo ini_get('error_reporting');
echo $unknown;
```

then this script will return

```
-1
Notice: Undefined variable: unknown in <filename> on line 4
```

even if your `php.ini` is set up differently (as it will be simply discarded anyway), and you are using the CGI version.

Also note that you can usually just use `ini_set` to set up the proper variables when the script starts, although there are some exceptions, like `output_handler`, which you can only properly set up in `php.ini`. Using `-n` to get rid of potential issues with non-standard ini files can be useful.

Also note you usually don't need to add the ending `?>` in a script, and not having it there can sometimes help with weird errors caused by unseen additional whitespace characters after the ending `?>`

Comment: ```-q``` does precisely nothing in CLI

Comment: @JoeWatkins unless on that particular box `/usr/bin/php` points to the cgi version of php, and some environment variables are set so PHP actually thinks it runs in CGI mode instead of CLI.

Comment: That would be quite strange, I don't think it's generally applicable advice.

Comment: @JoeWatkins The question was about how to make sure your code will run as similarly as possible if you don't really know how php is set up on a specific machine. If adding `-q` can help with that I would suggest it. I know this *should* not make any difference since PHP 5, where CLI mode was introduced, but the question was about how to better be safe than sorry, in case an admin just symlinks `php` to `php-cgi` for any reason (including trying to fix something the wrong way)